# Sagemaker file size limit?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I was wondering whether there is some size limit for storing a folder in sagemaker studio?
I have this dataset stored in s3 but I want to download that dataset in my sagemaker studio environment to train my model. Is there some kind of limit in the size of a file i can download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [home directory in Amazon SageMaker Studio is stored in Amazon EFS file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-tasks-manage-storage.html). The file system grows and shrink as you add and remove files.
According to [Amazon EFS limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#limits-fs-specific) the **maximum size for a single file is 47.9TiB.**